# webpart not detect language change

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, 2019, visual-web-part, web-part-pages, alternate-language

in our sharepoint website we have page include webpart .
site is using 2 language english and arabic
IF im login as Anonymous Users:
when change from englsh to arabic client side code detect not detect webpart language and display the page in arabic but webpart still showing in english

BUT if im login as sharepoint admin:
it is working and detect the language and change webpart language

what can be the issue here ?